# Xpath fetch specific nodes without their child nodes from XML

Tags: xpath, web-crawler

I have XML data that looks like this

```
<priceData>
  <div class='price'>
    <div class='price-old'>20.00</div>
    <div class='price-new'>10.00</div>
    <div class='price-tax'>8.00</div>
  </div>
  <div class='price'>
    40.00 <div class='price-tax'>25.00</div>
  </div>
 </priceData>
```

I want to use Xpath to extract data for "price-new" from the first price div, and value 40.00 from the second price div. This must be done using single expression.

I tried expressions like

```
//div[contains(@class, 'price') and not(contains(@class, 'tax')) and not(contains(@class, '-old'))]
```

and

```
//div[contains(@class, 'price') and not(contains(@class, 'tax')) and not(descendant::div[contains(@class, '-old') and not(contains(@class, '-tax'))]) and not(contains(@class, '-old'))]
```

and some others but I can't get it to work how it is supposed to.
I always end up with fetching extra nodes from the first case and I only need the single node (price-new or price if there are no more nodes in it).

Comment: What result do you need exactly? A node-set with two text nodes?

Comment: Yes, two text nodes. One from each case.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using xpath union (`|`) to combine 2 queries into one. Given markup in the question as XML input, the following xpath (formatted for readability) :

```
//div[@class='price']/div[@class='price-new']/text()
    | 
//div[@class='price']/text()[normalize-space()]
```

returned 'expected' result in [xpath tester](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html) :

```
Text='10.00'
Text='40.00'
```